# Monotone increasing function that has derivative 0 almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

The Cantor function is an example of a continuous monotone increasing function, whose derivative is 0 almost everywhere and maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. Is there an example of a continuous monotone increasing function $f:[0,1)\to[0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\infty$ and such that $f'=0$ a.e. on $[0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c: [0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$ denote the Cantor function and define $f:[0,1) \rightarrow [1,\infty)$ by $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Then $c$ and $f$ are monotone and continuous so their composition $g:=f \circ c$ is monotone and continuous. Clearly $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 1^-} g(x)=\infty$ and by the chain rule $g'(x)=f'(c(x)) c'(x)$ whenever $c'$ exists, so $g'=0$ a.e.

Comment: Does the answer change if we also require $f$ to be locally Lipschitz? Since the Cantor function isn't Lipschitz...

Comment: If $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz it is absolutely continuous which implies that $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f’$ $d\mu$ for $x\in [0, 1]$. So then if $f’=0$ a.e. $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch:

By dilating and translating the original Cantor function, you can get a monotone increasing function which has vanishing derivative a.e. between any two intervals.

Put $I_n=\left[1-\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right]$. Paste Cantor functions between each $I_n$ and $[n,n+1]$ to get what you want.